# How to send a image to Rest API?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need send a string (some Id) and a image (MediaFile) to a Rest API, but I can't figure out what I am doind wrong.

After a lot of research, I came to the next code, but still not working...

```
        public async Task<bool> CustomPostReportImage(string uri, string reportIdentifier, MediaFile image)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"); ;

                    content.Add(
                        new StringContent(
                            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                {
                                    { "reportIdentifier", reportIdentifier }
                                }
                                ),
                            Encoding.UTF8,
                            "application/json")
                            );

                    content.Add(new StreamContent(image.GetStream()),
                      "image",
                       image.Path);

                    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I was receiving some Java error, but now, after some changes, just returning 400 Bad Request.
[On postman I can easy do, like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTFng.png)

Comment: you need to know the specific requirements of the API - there are a million different ways it could be setup and we don't know anything about what you're using.  Your Postman capture also shows 9 Header values, none of which you are passing in your C# code.

Comment: The only true necessary that I put was the content-type... This API should be simple as can be.

Comment: Do you try to replace  `StreamContent` of `MultipartFormDataContent`? like these code:`var client = new HttpClient();
var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(new MemoryStream(foto).ToArray()), "foto", "foto.jpg");`